# Volume data persistence with wso2/wso2is-km

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wso2

I use wso2/wso2is-km in my docker-compose :

```
oAuth2:
    container_name: "oAuth2.local.fr"
    hostname: "oAuth2.local..fr"
    image: wso2/wso2is-km:5.10.0
    ports:
        - "9443:9443"
    links:
        - gui:gui.local.fr
        - bandeau:bandeau.local.fr
    volumes:
        - ./is-as-km:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-km-5.10.0
```

If I remove volumes it's ok but if I want persist data in host machine I add volume one error appear :

```
oAuth2.local.fr        /home/wso2carbon/docker-en ...   Exit 127
oAuth2.local.fr | sh: 0: Can't open /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-km-5.10.0/bin/wso2server.sh
```

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy wso2is-km-5.10.0/repository on host and mount volume :

```
volumes:
        - ./is-km:/home/wso2carbon/wso2-artifact-volume
```

On run /home/wso2carbon/wso2-artifact-volume is copied in wso2is-km-5.10.0 with docker-entrypoint.sh (default behavior).

Answer (score 0):

When you add the volume to wso2is-km-5.10.0, it replaces the content in the docker image and it has caused this issue.

When persisting data, we should use the following location.

```
wso2is-km-5.10.0/repository/deployment/server/
```

Comment: Hi @pubci, 
Thank's for explain.
I've tested, if I share wso2is-km-5.10.0/repository/deployment/server/  directory my application didn't redirect on login page but on carbon login. When I remove volume login page is show.

Comment: Looks like an issue. To overcome, can u copy the content in repository/deployment/server to your host directory and then use that host directory for the mount?

Comment: Same issue. As soon as mount volume the login is redirect on carbon login.... 
Strange behaviour